# View fliper not resizing if content is listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm having a problem that viewfliper doesnt resize when i load in a listview. My xml that contains viewfliper is:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mojprofil_scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/moj_profil_flipper"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <include layout="@layout/1" />
                <include layout="@layout/2" />
                <include layout="@layout/3" />
            </ViewFlipper>

    </ScrollView>
```

Evrything works fine with views that doesn't contain listview, but the one that contains it, is problamatic. It's design is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="15dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="17dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="sdfgsdg: "
        android:textColor="#2f96c4"
        android:textSize="19dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="serif" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dodaj_polico_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="add"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btn32_2x" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

</ListView>
```

The listview gets so small that it only shows one line but there is space on the screen for like 6-7 lines. It also depends from device to device but it always leaves a lot of space and shrink.

Comment: the only way i can fix that is by using a static height for listview but that way it looks stupid and on start it loads directly to start of listview...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my listView was inside viewFilper that was inside scrollView, so i removed scrollview and ow it works like a charm :D